# How can I have a table positioned?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

How can I prevent table cells from overlaping? I need to keep the table on the left within the table data in a fixed position so the data on the right requires scrolling the left td cell will remain there.

I have an example of the html here -

http://jsbin.com/ifiha4/edit#preview

and code -

```
<table ID="Table1" Width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="style2"> 
            <table border="" style="width:20%;position:fixed;left:54px; top: 84px;">
                <th>some table</th>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            some text blah blah blah    
        </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: can you be more specific or give an example of what it is you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td align="center" class="style2" style="width:100px;">
```

I think you should try setting widths on each column that you are using. Does this work for you?

The better way is to do this:

```
<div style="float:left; width:100px; border:1px solid black">

Column 1 content

</div>


<div style="float:left; width:100px; border:1px solid black">

Column 2 content

</div>
```

You will be happy you changed to div in the long run. :)

http://jsbin.com/ifiha4/7/edit#preview

Comment: That div is great but i need it in a fixed position as well the left side. I will be using a gridview in .net for the right div content which will require scrolling but i want the left to remain in position.

Comment: But i don't want the content from overlapping when the browser is minimised as well.

Comment: Do you mean like the feedback tag on the left of this website:http://www.knowledgesutra.com/discuss/tpdcoo-item-scroll.om     If you want just the gridview to scroll, you can make it scroll inside the right div tag. You mean you do not want it to just autosize the right div but you want to scroll keeping the height constant?